# Error caused by spacebar character

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a virtual machine (Virtual Box Version 5.2.18 r124319 (Qt5.6.3) ). I am coding in C on Visual Studio Code and every time I type a '=' followed or preceded by a space (any variable declaration for example), the compilation doesn't work because the space character is apparently recognised as a special character (see screenshot attached).

Has anyone encountered this problem and know how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

[image: Problems with space and Visual Studio on Ubuntu]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBn2L.png

Comment: Where are you editing the code?

Comment: I'm editing in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Try a real text editor like vi or nano (or Gedit / Kedit if you are in Gnome or KDE).

Comment: I got here starting my own question about "phantom space or tab" in JavaScript, also editing in Visual Studio Code. In error message in terminal nor in nano mine doesn't get displayed as a replacement character �.

Comment: Ok, mine seems to be a Zero Width Space unicode character u200b

Answer (score 3):

That's a non-breaking space, see [octals-302-240-together-seem-to-correspond-to-non-breaking-space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272161/octals-302-240-together-seem-to-correspond-to-non-breaking-space)  It's the result of using a word processor instead of a text editor.
You might be able to select what type of output your editor produces, or fix the output after the fact (like the sed edit pass in the link), or select another editor that outputs just what you type.